# HP Laserjet printer Installation issue

Tags: printing

HP laserjet 1007/1008,HP laserjet 1020 printers we are unable to install on Ubuntu 14.04.It gets installed automatically i.e Plug & play & can be seen in printers but print is not going.

Comment: Did you install driver?

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal window and type:

> sudo apt-get update
>    sudo apt-get install hplip hplip-gui

You can now check printing status in the graphical interface of HP-Print utilities.

Comment: We have tried these commands in terminal but print is not coming.Any plugins are needed to install.Please guide the complete procedure.

Comment: Here it is, directly from HP: http://hplipopensource.com/node/309

Comment: In Terminal after running hp-setup command while downloading plugins automatically from HP server getting the message "The printer you are trying to setup requires a binary driver plug-in and it failed to install.  Please check your internet connection and try again.  Visit  http://hplipopensource.com  for more infomation." But Interrnet connection is present on that machine.This has been tried 3-4 times.Even if we download plugin 3.16.8.run & give manual path for installation next tab remains disabled.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have a 1007, just a 1015 that works fine without any plugins. You'll have to ask HP about your problem.